Mongoose Aggregate to group by brand_id and orders_sum > threshold stored in another collections
Sample collection of Sales looks like this:
[
  {
    "brand_id": "A",
    "price": 500
  },
  {
    "brand_id": "A",
    "price": 700
  },
  {
    "brand_id": "B",
    "price": 1500
  },
  {
    "brand_id": "C",
    "price": 100
  },
  {
    "brand_id": "D",
    "price": 400
  },
  {
    "brand_id": "D",
    "price": 600
  },
  {
    "brand_id": "D",
    "price": 200
  }
]

This is my current solution:
    const data = await Sales.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$brand_id",
          total_sales: {
            $sum: "$price"
          },
          records: {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          total_sales: {
            $gt: 1000
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$records"
      },
      {
        $replaceWith: "$records"
      }
    ])

What am trying to do is, from the Sales collection, I am trying to get all the documents grouped by brand_id and each brands total order value to be greater than 1000$ (threshold value).
But I have another collection named Brands where it contains the brand_id, brand_name and threshold value.
So it would be like this:
[
  {
    brand_id:"A",
    brand_name: "abc",
    threshold: 1000,
  },
  {
    brand_id: "B",
    brand_name: "hef",
    threshold: 600,
  },
  {
    brand_id: "C",
    brand_name: "xyz",
    threshold: 310,
  }
]

The thing is, I can iterate through the documents of Brands and pass the threshold value to the aggregate function and call it each time. But it doesn't seem to be the proper approach.
I tried googling for a similar scenario. But couldn't find any.
What am expecting as output is something similar to this:
[
  "A":[
   {
     "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
     "brand_id": "A",
     "price": 500
   },
   {
     "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
     "brand_id": "A",
     "price": 700
   },
  ],
  "B":[
   {
     "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
     "brand_id": "B",
     "price": 1500
   },
  ],
  "D":[
   {
     "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
     "brand_id": "D",
     "price": 400
   },
   {
     "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
     "brand_id": "D",
     "price": 600
   },
   {
     "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000006"),
     "brand_id": "D",
     "price": 200
   }
  ]
]


In your Brands collection example, your brand_id & brand_name don't match with the brand_id in Sales. So how do you select/lookup which threshold value to apply?

@aneroid thanks for pointing that out. I wrote it as a quick sample and caused the typos. Fixed it now.

I would suggest you start the $lookup from the Brands collection to look up all the sales record. Use $sum on the $lookup result to get the total sales amount, then $match with the threshold value
db.brands.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "sales",
      "localField": "brand_id",
      "foreignField": "brand_id",
      "as": "salesLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "total_sales": {
        $sum: "$salesLookup.price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          "$total_sales",
          "$threshold"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Thank you. I have indexed the brand_id on both collections. Hope this would perform well when the dataset becomes bigger. Because right now am testing on a smaller dataset.
